# Fonts TOO LARGE on moble phone - How limit size or fix?

Tags: html, fonts, size, cell

I am using CSS and some of the fonts on my mobile are breaking up the Divs and not messing up the rest of the html. Is there a way to limit the font size in the css styled Divs?

For example I have a button that looks fine on computers but this same button text is too large or not the right size on my phone and does not appear correctly in the button.

I am including a picture of what it looks like on a computer.

I am using a DROID. If you are using your cell phone you can see the link here: http://www.edvizenor.com/?p=PicturePoll&id=33

[image]

Answer (score 4):

CSS [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) might be what you're looking for. You can change the font size (or whatever else you want) based on the device width, for example:

```
@media all and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    .changeThisFont {
        font-size: 0.5em;
    }
}
```

You might also add something like this in your HTML head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=600, initial-scale=1">
```